# Models in JS file in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

Can I put my Models-objects in JS file, and then reuse like a shared model?
It should look like this:

```
//Models.JS
var myModel = ListModel {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use QML types in JS (I assume it is Qt 4.x). If by "reuse" you mean share (like in global variable), you can put your model in global context as a context property. See [QDeclarativeContext::setContextProperty()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativecontext.html#setContextProperty). Another option would be create C++ model, where all instance would share same state.

If you don't want to have a single global instance, you can declare `ListModel { id: myModel }`in root element, and access it from children (even declared in other files).

```
Item {
    ListModel { id: myModel }
    Listview {
        id: one
        model: myModel
    }
    Listview {
        id: two
        model: myModel
    }
    // etc
}
```